# VBScript SMTP Auto Email

Tags: email, vbscript, smtp, cdo.message

I have a script to auto email a list of address' stored in Excel, but it is only sending to the first address and not looping to the rest, I cannot seem to fix it:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xls" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

set sh = wb.Sheets("Auto Email Script")
row = 2
email = sh.Range("A" & row)
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim f                                   
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail\Script\Email.txt", ForReading)                                        
BodyText = f.ReadAll

For r = row to LastRow
    If App.WorkSheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
    objMessage.Subject = "Billing: Meter Read" 
    objMessage.From = "billing@energia.ie"
    row = row + 1
    objMessage.To = email
    objMessage.TextBody = BodyText

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2


'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "SERVER ADDRESS HERE"

'Server port
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMessage.Send

    End if
Next

f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
wb.Close
End If
Next
```

Any help would be much appreciated guys!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot of the xls and the text file? So that I can be sure the we are looking into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row = 2
email = sh.Range("A" & row)
...
For r = row to LastRow
  ...
  objMessage.To = email
  ...
Next
```

You set `email` to the value of the cell `"A2"` and never change it. If you want to send a mail to multiple recipients, you should make that

```
objMessage.To = sh.Range("A" & r).Value
```

or (better) build a recipient list (assuming that your used range starts with headers in the first table row):

```
ReDim recipients(LastRow - row)
For r = row To LastRow
  recipients(r - row) = sh.Range("A" & r).Value
Next
objMessage.To = Join(recipients, ";")
```

and send the message just once. The MTA will handle the rest.

---

**Side note:** as Vishnu Prasad Kallummel pointed out in the comments your code doesn't close the Excel instance it started. Unlike other objects created in VBScript, Office applications won't automatically terminate with the script, so you have to handle it yourself:

```
...
wb.Close
app.Quit
```

Comment: The loop has to be terminated with LastRow+1 and the excel application(process) is not being/getting closed.

Comment: The loop is fine as it is when the used range starts with the first row (headers, for instance). Good point about the application instance. Added a note WRT that.